# Samba Permissions Issue, moved shared folder to external drive

Tags: server, permissions, samba, file-sharing

I am running Ubuntu Server on a rasp pi 400

I installed samba, created samba user and password, created a shared folder with samba(user) as owner and group. This shared folder was located under /home/samba/shared_folder. Set up my config file to point to that folder. All is good, i can access it through my android phonw, my windows computer and my arch laptop. I copied a few files over for test.

My next idea was to move the shared folder over to a larger external ssd (2280 nvme in an enclosure) this ssd is mounted on boot in my /etc/fstab

I mv'd the folder, i think as root, to the external drive and pointed the smb.conf to the new path.

Everytime i try to copy a file into samba drive i get permissions denied error.

I checked ownership of the shared folder in new location and changed both owner and group to "samba" (the user i added on ubuntu server system to use samba and sign in on other computers)

I did chmod 755 /mnt/ext1/shared_folder

Nothing so far has worked. I had a working samba server prior to moving the shared folder. I can still view the shared folder on other devices but i cannot copy new files to the samba drive. I want to update a log i keep for example to the server but i keep getting permissions denied.

Please advise, thank you for your help.

edit: Moving my shared folder (and the path in smb.conf) back to /home/samba/shared_folder allows me to use the drive as normal again, but the shared folder is located on my sd card which is running the server. I would much rather store the samba files on my external drive, if anyone has ideas as to what i did wrong.

Comment: Please update question with output of `cat /etc/smb.conf`